# How would a witch/wizard repair Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

The damage after the Battle of Hogwarts in 1998 was severe and extensive. Most of the castle was in ruins by the end, and it did not look the same at all. In the "19 Years Later" portion of the series, we see the next generation going to Hogwarts, which we can easily infer that it has been fixed (at least usable).

We also know that Reparo, or the Mending Charm, will fix objects ([As such](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Mending_Charm)). How big can of an object can Reparo mend? We see that in the sixth book in the series, Albus supposedly uses the Mending Charm to fix a Muggle's house after it had been destroyed by Horace. This charm may not have been Reparo, however, its effects were quite extensive.

How would a witch/wizard(s) fix Hogwarts? Would the Mending Charm (Reparo) do the job?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It’s quite possible that Reparo would be sufficient to repair Hogwarts. In the game *Wonderbook: Book of Spells* (which is considered canon), there’s a scene which gives us the history and background of Reparo. There’s a [playthrough on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKq3GyuigHM&t=10m30s), and I’ve transcribed the relevant portions here:

> Many repairing and mending charms have been used over the centuries, but the most effective and powerful was invented by Orabella Nuttley in the eighteenth century. […]
>
> In 1754, two of Europe's most celebrated broom fliers – sworn enemies Torquil MacTavish, of Scotland, Silvio Astolfi of Italy agreed to a public broom race from Aberdeen to Rome. […] Precisly what happened is hotly contested to this day, but a large explosion ensued, and when the smoke cleared Silvio Astolfi had been turned into a chicken, Torquil MacTavish's knees were on back to front and the Colosseum lay in ruins.
>
> For a few horrific minutes, it appeared that the assembled crowd had witnessed the greatest breach the International Statute of Secrecy ever known. Not only were they at a loss to know how to repair such massive damage, but the sound of the explosion had already woken half of Rome.
>
> **It was then that Orabella Nuttley came quietly forwards and, with a few waves of her wand reconstructed several columns with the use of her own Repairing Charm.** Stunned at its efficacy, the governmental Ministers begged her to teach them how to use the new spell and by the time the first anxious Muggles had dressed and rushed to the scene, they found nothing, but the Colosseum in exactly the state they had last seen it, and a few oddly dressed men trying to soothe a distressed chicken. Orabella received the Order of Merlin, First Class, and her Mending Charm has been in widespread use ever since.

Hogwarts is an order of magnitude larger than the Colosseum, but it seems plausible that you could still use Reparo for a building of this size:

- If you repaired it in Colosseum-sized chunks, rather than all-in-one-go, the problem seems eminently tractable.
- You have more people, who probably know more about the spell (it has an extra 250 years of usage and research since Nuttley’s time), and thus are able to use it more effectively. They probably also have more combined magical power than a single witch.
- It’s quite possible that Hogwarts has some mechanisms for self-repair, or at least to assist in the process. It’s a magical building, not a static one. Depending on the enchantments placed on it by the builders, it might “know” how it’s supposed to fit together, which would presumably assist with the reconstruction process.

Ultimately, I don’t think canon ever tells us exactly how Hogwarts was repaired. I don’t recall any interviews along those lines. But based on the evidence above, it seems that a team of people could probably repair the castle using Reparo alone.

Comment: Even with the power of Reparo, I doubt that the whole of Hogwarts could have been repaired in one go. To my mind, it would have needed a whole host of wizard volunteers (or a Ministry of Magic repair crew, if such a thing existed) moving around the castle, casting Reparo one room/staircase/turret at a time.

Comment: It might have been like how the wizards/witches repaired New York City at the end of the Fantastic Beast movie.

Answer (score 5):

## They could use Repairing Charms, like in *Fantastic Beasts*.

In the spin-off movie *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, after the city of New York is wrecked by a rampaging (spoiler), the Aurors use Repairing Charms to fix the damage that was done.

> “Aurors move through the streets, performing Repairing Charms to rebuild the city: Buildings and cars are reconstructed and streets are returned to normal.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

The damage to New York was fairly large-scale and expansive, so it seems like this method should work on Hogwarts as well.

The Repairing Charm is never given an incantation in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, and no charm that’s specified as the Repairing Charm is mentioned in any of the books or movies. However, in *Wonderbook: Book of Spells*, Reparo is referred to as the Repairing Charm (as well as the Mending Charm). Presuming this is true, then Reparo could indeed be used on large-scale damage like what had occurred at Hogwarts.